# Using a non-default color shema for gedit syntax highlighter

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gedit

I wrote a simple gedit xml lang file for do highlighting source code. When i use constructions like

```
<style id="comment" _name="Comment" map-to="def:comment"/>
<style id="keyword" _name="Keyword" map-to="def:keyword"/>
```

it always color comments blue and keywords brown. I would instead like my comments green and keywords red. How can I do that?

I also noticed some schemas under `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/styles`:

```
classic.xml  cobalt.xml  kate.xml  oblivion.xml  styles.rng  tango.xml
```

How can I use these in my lang file?

Answer (score 4):

The lang files do not describe styles. The lang defines the language (this is a keyword, this is comment, etc.) and the style describes how to display those things (make comments green, make keywords blue and bold, etc.). It's up to the end user to choose the style based on there preferences.

You can select a style in the Gedit preferences dialog. As it happens, the "Kate" style does color comments green and keywords red, so you should use that one.

Take note that the paths for where you store the style and lang files is different in Gedit 2 and Gedit 3 (GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3).

Comment: thanks, i choose my own style in /styles, now the keywords are colorized as i wanted. the only thing remains that the keywords must be typed only in latin charset and my Cyrillic keywords are not recognized by my lang file :( this is the other problem i ran into